# Unable to install js-beautify

Tags: node.js, js-beautify

Unable to install js-beautify, what is happening here. Not sure why it is failing here, can someone help

```
nvm

Node Version Manager

Usage:
    nvm help                    Show this message
    nvm install [-s] <version>  Download and install a <version>
    nvm uninstall <version>     Uninstall a version
    nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>
    nvm run <version> [<args>]  Run <version> with <args> as arguments
    nvm ls                      List installed versions
    nvm ls <version>            List versions matching a given description
    nvm ls-remote               List remote versions available for install
    nvm deactivate              Undo effects of NVM on current shell
    nvm alias [<pattern>]       Show all aliases beginning with <pattern>
    nvm alias <name> <version>  Set an alias named <name> pointing to <version>
    nvm unalias <name>          Deletes the alias named <name>
    nvm copy-packages <version> Install global NPM packages contained in <version> to current version

Example:
    nvm install v0.4.12         Install a specific version number
    nvm use 0.2                 Use the latest available 0.2.x release
    nvm run 0.4.12 myApp.js     Run myApp.js using node v0.4.12
    nvm alias default 0.4       Auto use the latest installed v0.4.x version
```

This is how we are installing js-beautify

```
jeff@paris:~$ nvm install js-beautify
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/jeff/.nvm/bin/node-N/A-linux-x64/node-N/A-linux-x64.tar.gz: 
Warning: No such file or directory
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 162)
Binary download failed, trying source.
Additional options while compiling: 
nvm: install N/A failed!
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Really ? He is using the wrong command. See Alberto's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nvm` is a node version manager. `npm` is the node package manager.

You should use `npm` to install packages

```
npm install js-beautify
```